# Fetching Firebase data in React shows up after render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When fetching Firebase data in React on the client-side, my images, for example, show up after my component is rendered.

I fetch the data in the componentDidMount method and have tried UNSAFE_componentWillMount, but the results are the same.

I am wondering if the data is fetched with an API, would that mean that my front-end and my data would render at the same time?

I am sorry if this question is stupid, I am just trying to figure out whether serverless databases can 
scale with large amounts of data or whether you need a database and fetch data on the server-side to reach top performance and have your data render with your front end, so that on page load, the user doesn't experience latency.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little confused on what your question is, fetches in componentDidMount will begin after the component is mounted and will trigger a rerender after the fetch is done.

Comment: Yes, so how can I fetch the data on first-page load, so my content doesn't rerender with the new data, but appears on the page when it first loads.

Comment: If you really need data to be preloaded, server-side rendering is the best option. Otherwise, it's best to fetch after the skeleton of the page is rendered https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: Yea, thought so. Thanks man.